# How to put placeholder icon into contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to put the icon as a placeholder into contact form 7 with following codes. There are 3 icons, but only 1 icon was put successfully. Is there anybody can help check the issue?

1. This is my code for contact form.

```
<p><span class="fa fa-user"></span>[text* your-name placeholder:"YOUR NAME"] </div>
<p><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>[email* your-email placeholder:"YOUR EMAIL"] </p>
<p><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>[textarea your-message placeholder:"YOUR MESSAGE"] </p>
<p style=”text-align: center;”>[submit class:btn "Send"]</p>
```

2. To put icon into placeholder, I used the codes below, but only fa-user icon was put into placeholder successfully. The others are still in the labels

```
div.wpcf7 {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpcf7 .wpcf7-text,
.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-textarea {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.wpcf7 p { position: relative; }
.wpcf7 p .fa {
  position: absolute;
  color: #666666;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 18%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the code below!!!

```
.wpcf7-form input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea {
    width:100% !important;
}

.wpcf7 .wpcf7-text, .wpcf7 .wpcf7-email, .wpcf7 .wpcf7-textarea {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.wpcf7 p { position: relative; }
.wpcf7 p .fa-user, .wpcf7 p .fa-envelope {
  position: absolute;
  color: #666666;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 18%;
  left: 3%;
}

.wpcf7 p .fa-pencil {
  position: absolute;
  color: #666666;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 6%;
  left: 3%;
}
```